# Libreoffice new version instead of upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice

When I try `apt remove libreoffice` I get no libreoffice installed.

But I have installed new one with recommended `dpkg -i *.deb`

And now I have old version 7.0 which starts when I type `libreoffice` and new version which starts when I type `libreoffice7.4`

How do I get rid of old libreoffice since it's not installed via ppa?

It is not listed in snap list as well

I think that it was also installed via dpkg -i

Comment: You've not mentioned how it was installed; as to remove an application you reverse the installation procedure.  ie. if it was a *snap* package thus installed with `snap install` then it's `snap remove`, if it's a *deb* package installed with `apt install` then it's removed with `apt remove`, however if it's ... flatpak.... appimage....from source...   ie. you've not said how it was installed, or what type of package it was & Ubuntu has many *package* options. You've also not mentioned your OS/release so we can't narrow it down to what options you may have *easily* available to you either.

Comment: @guiverc updated it is not snap. I think it was dpkg -i

Comment: For `dpkg -i *.deb`, where did you download the deb files from? Where did you download it to? Who recommended this? Why not ask whoever recommended it what the recommended way to remove it is then?

Comment: @muru their official readme... dpkg's are all targzipped